# Texture state usage warning

Tags: opengl

I have the following case:
I have a material which has 2 textures -diffuse and alpha mask.
In most cases the alpha mask is not used while the sampler for it in the relevant fragment shader still defined.It works ok, but if I turn on gl debug output I am getting the following warning:

> Severity:Low ,Message:Texture state usage warning:Texture 1 is base
>   level inconsistent.Check texture size.

The warning is produced when alpha mask target has no binding.

I have 2 questions:

1. Can this warning have any negative impact on the rendering?
2. If the first answer is "Yes" then how can unused samplers be disabled so that this type of warning is not produced?(Something which is not using preprocessors in GLSL as it may change in runtime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not have any impact, unless you hit some driver optimization voodoo case, to disable this warning you might want to use separate shaders for cases when alpha has binding and does not have binding.

Comment: I wouldn't want using separate shaders in such a case as it definitely  impact performance because of shader pipelines switch.

Comment: @MichaelIV actually that depends on your shader, it might be optimized by throwing away some branching code that checks whether to use alpha, branching is expensive on GPU. It could outperform shader switch.

Comment: I use subroutines to escape branching :)

Comment: @MichaelIV But somehow you choose whether to call subroutine with alpha or without it.